# "Fail" keyword in jenkins console should fail the jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I wish to fail the jenkins build if there's any "Fail" keyword in jenkins console log. How would I do this?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Conditional BuildStep Plugin, with the option string match. If the condition fits you cant fail the build f.e. with a shell script and exit 1.